# ClassNotFoundException mopub in my FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, buildpath, mopub

I'm trying to add mopub to my app. I installed the sdk through the AndroidStudio plugin. and added this to my xml

```
 <com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview
   android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
</com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview>
```

But it gives me these errors:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
```

and when I run the app it crashes:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hroshandel.myapplication/com.example.hroshandel.myapplication.SimpleIntro_FragmentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview
>
> at com.example.hroshandel.myapplication.SimpleIntro_FragmentActivity.onCreate(SimpleIntro_FragmentActivity.java:20)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hroshandel.myapplication-4.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.hroshandel.myapplication-4, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: You could check the classpath to see if the com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview is in it. If it is, you can use dex2jar (https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and look inside your apk if the .class file is there.

Comment: @BogdanV. I checked my project structure and 
com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:3.2.2@aar is in my dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

please check the the typo of the class name, a genius write in the documentation:

```
<com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview
   android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
</com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview>
```

but the right class name is:

```
    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView> ... </com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView>
```

Comment: Oh the irony. I literally copy & pasted this part from twitter's "getting started" guide just to be sure that I do not make any typos. Fixing twitter's typo did the trick for me, too. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you'll have to fix your gradle as noted in the above answer. But beyond that I had the same error message running the app and here was how I was able to get around it:

1. Remove the design time reference to the MoPub adview.

```xml
    <com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview
       android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
    </com.mopub.mobileads.mopubview>
```

2. In its stead, put a container. I chose to use a FrameLayout:

```xml
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/adContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    </FrameLayout>
```

3. In the Activity, I loaded the MoPubView programmatically by instantiating it, assigning and loading my ad, and then using the BannerAdListener onBannerLoaded event to add it to the adContainer:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); // optional library
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        ButterKnife.inject(this); // optional, used to inject views e.g. adContainer

        MoPubView moPubView = new MoPubView(this);

        moPubView.setAdUnitId("ad unit id");
        moPubView.loadAd();
        moPubView.setBannerAdListener(new MoPubView.BannerAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBannerLoaded(MoPubView moPubView) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Banner loaded");
                try {
                    mAdContainer.addView(moPubView);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error loading banner add to container");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBannerFailed(MoPubView moPubView, MoPubErrorCode moPubErrorCode) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Banner failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBannerClicked(MoPubView moPubView) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Banner clicked");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBannerExpanded(MoPubView moPubView) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Banner expanded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBannerCollapsed(MoPubView moPubView) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Banner collapsed");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious question did you followed setup process https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/getting-started

EDIT:

There is GRADLE

Copy into your project

```
$MY_PROJECT_DIR $ mkdir mopub-sdk
$MY_PROJECT_DIR $ cp -R $MOPUB_DIR/mopub-android-sdk/mopub-sdk mopub-sdk
```

Add to your build.gradle

```
include ':app', ':mopub-sdk'
dependencies { compile project(':mopub-sdk') }
```

Comment: I believe I did. The tutorial is for eclipse not android studio. when i want to add the sdk it doesn't recognize mopud-sdk as a module

Comment: I did this and in mopub-sdk in some classes it get this error: cannot resolve symbol millennialmedia. This error is at import com.millennialmedia.android.MMAd;